# Cord plug amperage rating for 3-phase machine

Tags: wiring

If i have 3 phase running to  a machine with 35 amp breakers how many amps should my cord ends be rated for ?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score -1):

3 Phase NEMA cord caps jump from 30 amps to 50 amps so you would need a 50.
 What is the voltage? this will define the style of outlet and cord cap.
480 V would use a NEMA L16-50 this is a true 3 phase with ground (4 wire). If you are using a system that also requires a neutral you will need the 5 wire.